# Reference table overflow caused by SimpleDateFormat.format()

Tags: java, android

I have an android project and there's an activity that need to display current time on the screen. So I used a working thread which post a message into main thread handler once per second. And in the handler, I format the current time and display it on UI. But I got a reference table overflow problem after running about every 30 mins, and my program was crashed by the error. Here's the log:

```
ReferenceTable overflow (max=1024)
JNI pinned array reference table (0x6080b458) dump:
  Last 10 entries (of 1024):
     1023: 0x423b76d0 int[] (1 elements)
     1022: 0x4209cea0 int[] (1 elements)
     1021: 0x4209c890 int[] (1 elements)
     1020: 0x42242198 int[] (1 elements)
     1019: 0x421b7b60 int[] (1 elements)
     1018: 0x420c0e08 int[] (1 elements)
     1017: 0x42107c18 int[] (1 elements)
     1016: 0x421078e8 byte[] (1 elements)
     1015: 0x42116a18 int[] (1 elements)
     1014: 0x42116408 int[] (1 elements)
  Summary:
        1 of byte[] (1 elements)
     1023 of int[] (1 elements) (1023 unique instances)
Failed adding to JNI pinned array ref table (1024 entries)
"main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
  | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x417f5de0 self=0x417e44a8
  | sysTid=7820 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1074331988
  | state=R schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=972 stm=228 core=0
  at libcore.icu.NativeDecimalFormat.formatLong(Native Method)
  at libcore.icu.NativeDecimalFormat.formatLong(NativeDecimalFormat.java:253)
  at java.text.DecimalFormat.format(DecimalFormat.java:684)
  at java.text.NumberFormat.format(NumberFormat.java:299)
  at java.text.DecimalFormat.format(DecimalFormat.java:702)
  at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.appendNumber(SimpleDateFormat.java:785)
  at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.append(SimpleDateFormat.java:676)
  at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.formatImpl(SimpleDateFormat.java:553)
  at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.format(SimpleDateFormat.java:818)
  at java.text.DateFormat.format(DateFormat.java:307)
  at com.tuyou.tsd.launcher.SleepingActivity.updateTime(SleepingActivity.java:206)
  at com.tuyou.tsd.launcher.SleepingActivity.access$1(SleepingActivity.java:204)
  at com.tuyou.tsd.launcher.SleepingActivity$2.handleMessage(SleepingActivity.java:66)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5146)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:732)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:566)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
VM aborting
Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) at 0x00001e8c (code=-6), thread 7820 (com.tuyou.tsd)
```

I noticed that the crash happened in the SimpleDateFormat.format() method call. By looking into the source code, I found the method just implement by

```
return format(date, new StringBuffer(), new FieldPosition(0)).toString();
```

So I'm wondering is it possible the StringBuffer and FieldPosition caused the memory leak? Or my program running too fast so the object can't get clean soon, so caused too much objects in the ref table? Here's my implement codes:

```
public class SleepingActivity extends BaseActivity {
…
private TimeTask mTimeTask = null;
private SimpleDateFormat mDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm", Locale.CHINA);
private Date mCurrentTime = new Date();
…

private Handler mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
        case 100:
            updateTime();
            break;
        default:
            super.handleMessage(msg);
        }
    }
};

private void updateTime() {
    mCurrentTime.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
    String time = mDateFormat.format(mCurrentTime); // problem happened here!
    if (mTimeView != null) {
        mTimeView.setText(time);
    }
}

private class TimeTask extends Thread {
    private boolean stop;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Looper.getMainLooper();
        while (!stop) {
            Message msg = Message.obtain(null, 100);
            mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
            try { Thread.sleep(1000); } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        }
    }   
}
…

}
```

Please help… Thx.

===========================================================
Edit:
Just trying to find the root cause, by comment out all of lines in updateTime(), after running still about 30 mins. I got another reference table overflow error, which seems different than before.

```
ReferenceTable overflow (max=1024)
JNI pinned array reference table (0x60865460) dump:
  Last 10 entries (of 1024):
     1023: 0x42269d20 int[] (1 elements)
     1022: 0x42269478 int[] (1 elements)
     1021: 0x42262e50 int[] (1 elements)
     1020: 0x42262dc0 int[] (1 elements)
     1019: 0x42262d28 byte[] (1 elements)
     1018: 0x4225d800 int[] (1 elements)
     1017: 0x42258af0 int[] (1 elements)
     1016: 0x42256940 int[] (1 elements)
     1015: 0x422535d0 int[] (1 elements)
     1014: 0x42251390 int[] (1 elements)
  Summary:
        1 of byte[] (1 elements)
     1023 of int[] (1 elements) (1023 unique instances)

Failed adding to JNI pinned array ref table (1024 entries)
"Binder_3" prio=5 tid=24 RUNNABLE
  | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x42151ee0 self=0x60ae8008
  | sysTid=5507 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1627171640
  | state=R schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=2 stm=1 core=0
  at android.os.Parcel.nativeEnforceInterface(Native Method)
  at android.os.Parcel.enforceInterface(Parcel.java:451)
  at android.app.ApplicationThreadNative.onTransact(ApplicationThreadNative.java:383)
  at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
VM aborting
```

Comment: It doesn't explain your problem but why don't you just use a `Chronometer` which handles all of this for you (including updating its own `TextView`?

Comment: Well, I never use this widget before :) I think I will try that. Thanks for your hint. But I still want to figure out my problem here.

Comment: Tried to use Chronometer, but still had the same reference table overflow problem after 30 mins. I think this problem is device specific. I ran this program on our custom android device. Maybe the ROM is not strong enough then the general android ROM. So since the error is ref table overflow, is there a way to check what objects in the ref table?

Answer (score 0):

I found the root cause of this problem. It's nothing to do with Java methods, it's one of my JNI function call, which is used

```
(*env)->GetByteArrayElements(env,buf, NULL)
```

to allocate an array, but didn't release it after use. So after running 30 mins, the ref table is overflow. By added

```
(*env)->ReleaseByteArrayElements(env, buf, buf_char, JNI_ABORT);
```

the problem is never happened again.